# How to show indicator on all tabs by default in react navigation

Tags: react-native, react-redux, react-navigation, react-redux-firebase

I have tab based navigation in one of my react native component. I'm using React Navigation v1. React Navigation shows tab indicator only for the current active tab.

[image]

However, I want every tabs to show tab indicator (bottom border on tab) by default but with different colors of course. And when active, each tab will show slightly different shade of the color.

I have tried with React Navigation v1, v2, Native Base. Couldn't find a way around.

I want the tab bar exactly like this image.

[image]

In React Navigation, we have something like this :

```
TabNavigator(
  { 
    Tab1: { screen: Tab1Component },
    Tab2: { screen: Tab2Component }
  },
  {
    tabBarComponent: TabBarTop,
    tabBarPosition: 'top',
    tabBarOptions: {
      indicatorStyle: {
        borderBottomColor: '#6495ed',
        borderBottomWidth: 2
      }
    }
  }
)
```

But this adds the style to the entire tabs. I want some ability to be applied on each tab basis. Same with Native Base's `tabBarUnderlineStyle`.

Answer (score 1):

You should use this props in your **tabBarOptions** inside **TabNavigatorConfig**

**activeTintColor** - Label and icon color of the active tab.

**activeBackgroundColor** - Background color of the active tab.

**inactiveTintColor** - Label and icon color of the inactive tab.

**inactiveBackgroundColor** - Background color of the inactive tab.

Comment: Can I use **tabBarOptions** inside each of the screens, you know inside of the **navigationOptions** function ?

Comment: yeah, there are some properties that are set when you initialize the TabNavigator and others that can be customized per-screen in navigationOptions.
read this https://v1.reactnavigation.org/docs/tab-based-navigation.html

Comment: nope. `tabBarOptions` is part of the TabNavigatorConfig. And is not available in the navigationOptions used by TabNavigator. There are others available such as `tabBarVisible`, `tabBarIcon`, `tabBarLabel` but except `tabBarOptions`.

Comment: yeah you are right, tabBarOptions is part of the TabNavigatorConfig